# roscore fails to start

Tags: ros, network, ros-ip, roscore, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just recently moved.  My project worked before, but I cannot even run roscore now.  This is the error I have received.  Does anyone know a fix?

```
ecejames01@ECE521:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/ecejames01/.ros/log/314256dc-9f5b-11e4-96a8-000a9de008e4/roslaunch-ECE521-2982.log
Checkingt log directory for disk usage.  This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage.  Usage is <1GB.

Unable to contact my own server at [http://ECE521:43402/}.
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

A common cause is that the machine cannot ping itself.  Please check for errors by running:

    ping ece521

For more tips, please see

    http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup
```

ping ece521 gives me: `ping: unknown host ece521`

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

---

### EDIT:

In a new terminal window, here are the results from commands:

```
ecejames01@ECE521:~$ hostname
ECE521
ecejames01@ECE521:~$ echo $ROS_HOSTNAME

ecejames01@ECE521:~$ echo $ROS_IP
68.55.84.72
ecejames01@ECE521:~$ echo $ROS_MASTER_URI
http://localhost:11311
```

Running `ifconfig eth0` gives me `inet addr: 10.0.0.9`.
My `localhost` is `127.0.0.1`.

Forcing ROS using these methods allows roscore to run:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
roscore

export ROS_IP=MY_IP_ADDRESS
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://$ROS_IP:11311
roscore
```

Thanks [gvdhoorn](http://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) for all your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201225/roscore-fails-to-start/) by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 323 on 2015-01-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ping ece521 gives me: `ping: unknown host ece521`

Make sure your current hostname is actually `ece521`. If it isn't (which your `ping` output seems to suggest), make sure you aren't forcing ROS to set `ROS_MASTER_URI` (or `ROS_HOSTNAME`) to include that incorrect name (check your `.bashrc`).

> My project worked before, but I cannot even run roscore now.

The ROS middleware needs a properly working network. If that is not available, `roscore` can't start.

---

Edit: before trying more complicated things, first try to force ROS to use bare IPs, instead of hostnames. In a fresh terminal:

```
export ROS_IP=YOUR_IP_ADDRESS
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://$ROS_IP:11311/
```

Then try to start just `roscore` in that same terminal.

You can retrieve your IP either through the Network Manager, or by simply running `ifconfig eth0` (provided you are using your (first) wired NIC).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-01-19**:
This is what I got:

```
ecejames01@ECE521:~$ hostname
ECE521
ecejames01@ECE521:~$ hostname -i
hostname: Name or service not known
ecejames01@ECE521:~$ hostname -y
hostname: Local domain name not set
```

I checked .bashrc and didn't see anything changing the ROS_MASTER_URI/HOSTNAME.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-20**:
afaik, `hostname` will return whatever is configured locally. You might want to make sure your local hostname/dns/network configuration is consistent with what your network admin has configured for you in the DNS & DHCP. If `ece521` does not resolve to an IP, you will get problems.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-01-20**:
I am relatively new to this beast called Linux, so I probably need a walk-through, if you don't mind, since my Google search hasn't helped me much.  I am on my home router.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-01-27**:
Both of these worked:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
echo $ROS_MASTER_URI
http://localhost:11311
roscore
```

and

```
export ROS_IP=MY_IP_ADDRESS
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://$ROS_IP:11311/
roscore
```

However, I have to run both sets of commands for each new terminal window. Thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-27**:
So that would seem to be a DNS issue then. Note that setting `$ROS_HOSTNAME` to `localhost` will prevent multi-pc setups to work properly.

> However, I have to run both sets of commands for each new terminal window

You could add the two export statements to your `~/.bashrc`.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-01-27**:
Is there any way to correct the DNS issue?

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-01-27**:
Also, something I have noticed since moving is that something is unusual with using sudo...for example:

```
ecejames01@ECE521:~$ sudo echo hello_world
sudo: unable to resolve host ECE521
[sudo] password for ecejames01: 
hello_world
ecejames01@ECE521:~$
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-27**:
I would systematically check your hostname/dns setup on your local machine as well as on any routers/home gateways/what-have-you. Also check `/etc/resolve.conf`, NetworkManager, `/etc/hosts` etc. If all else fails it might pay to do a `sudo grep -i ece521 -r /` and see what comes up.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-01-27**:
Maybe see this question/answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/59517/37292

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-01-27**:
[jarvisschultz](http://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/): I checked that site out and made the appropriate changes.  It fixed my `sudo: unable to resolve host ECE521` issue.  Still no-go on roscore.  I will continue to investigate as [gvdhoorn](http://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) suggested.  I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux, so any info to help me configure my network so roscore works...

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-01-27**:
Now when I attempt to run `roscore`, I get:

```
... logging to /home/ecejames01/.ros/log/bb787ab2-a658-11e4-a844-000a9de008e4/roslaunch-ECE521-2610.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1G
```

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-01-27**:
Then it just gets stuck until I `KeyboardInterrupt`.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-01-27**:
Okay...I'm an idiot.  Checked my .bashrc and found `export ROS_IP=68.55.84.72` there for some reason.  Took that out and everything seems to be running peachy-keen.  I don't remember why I had set my ROS_IP in my .bashrc.

Lessons learned: Comment changes with dates and reasons.

Thanks all!!!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-27**:
I distinctly remember asking you to check your `~/.bashrc` file in my first answer .. ;).

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-01-27**:
You did...lol.  You said check for `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_HOSTNAME`, not `ROS_IP`.  Sorry...I'm too new to know to look for anything other than what you said.

But once you walked me through the `export ROS_IP=MY_IP_ADDRESS`, I learned what you were trying to get me to do and what to look for.